# AVPlayer plays without notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, avplayer

In my app, I have 2 AVPlayers that play simultaneously, perfectly. I just load them up, and play, no notifications added, like so:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstVideo.videoURL]];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
self.player1 = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
[fullPlayer setMovieToPlayer:self.player1];
[self.player1 play];

//same code for the second player, but with another player and asset
```

Now when I change one of the players from just [player play] to the following, it never plays:

`viewDidLoad`:

```
[[self.player1 currentItem] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.player1.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (self.player1.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [self.player1 play];
        } else if (self.player1.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
        }
    }
}
```

The player without a notification waiting to be ready to play works fine and plays like normal, without any notifications or event listeners, while the one with the observer never fails but never plays. Any idea why??

Comment: Did you try to add your observer to self.player1 and not the currentItem?

Answer (score 0):

Add notification to self.player1, Adding notification to currentItem will not work. Remember to remove the notification when dealloc.